# apache rewrite rule to change https to http requests for specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All my incoming `http://` traffic is changed to `https://www.example.com` 
i want to enable `http` for specific file request eg. `http://www.example.com/crossdomain.xml`

below is my current rewrite rule: -

```
    RewriteEngine On
      # change https to http for specific file called "crossdomain.xml"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/crossdomain.xml
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/crossdomain.xml
      # change https to http for specific url/dir access called "/speedtest/"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/speedtest
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}%/speedtest [L,R=301]

    #rewirte all traffic to https excepth the /speedteset and /crossdomain.xml

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/speedtest/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/crossdomain.xml
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ON  ,the rewrite rules worked

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ON    #added this condition to get it working
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/crossdomain.xml
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/crossdomain.xml

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/speedtest
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}%/speedtest [L,R=301]


    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/speedtest/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/crossdomain.xml
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```